# Set jQuery accordion so that 2nd pane is default-opened; and more troubleshooting

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm using the accordion code found on [this site](http://drublic.de/blog/how-to-build-accordion-using-css-and-jquery/). My version of the code is only slightly changed, but I'm seeing a few differences in how my accordion acts, versus his.

1. I'm not able to both open and close a pane by clicking its header. (Works in his code, not in mine)
2. I'm not able to have the first pane opened by default. (works in his code, not in mine)
3. I'd like to set the second of two panes to be opened by default. (new)

Here's [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/Leigh/keQKz/2/). "Search" is not a pane, it will always be visible. The content under "Tools" and "Member Info" is the bits in an accordion, and Tools and Member Info are the clickable headers.

In my code, I changed the sections to divs, and when I run the code through Firebug, I get an error that says

```
$('.accordion-item').eq(1).addClass('current').find('.content').show();
```

But I'm not sure why it's not defined. I changed the element, I didn't remove the accordion-item class. jQuery is listed in the header, and it's the only JavaScript file referenced in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

How do I modify the code to get it to work like his; and how can I modify the code to add in the functionality that I want (point the third)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found it. I had jquery's file name misspelled: was jquery-1.8.2.js, should have been jquery-1.8.2.min.js. Always...never...forget to check your references.